# Visualising set of continuous (but not differentiable) functions

Tags: calculus, functions

In order to visualize  set of differentiable functions I think of thing that records output of seismometer (helicorder ?), so in order to draw any differentiable function you move paper from right to left (at constant speed) and move pencil up and down (speed depends on function you are plotting but must be finite) (now, I cannot prove this but it kind of seems correct).

So is it possible to modify this setup (ie. by applying different set of rules to speed of pencil and paper) to draw continuous functions that are not differentiable (at finite number of points) too?

Comment: not differentiable at finite points or on the entire domain?

Comment: not differentiable at finite points.

Comment: just make a corner... Is that within the rules? (for instance, the derivative of $|x|$ is not defined at $x=0$, there is a corner or "sharp turn" there)

Comment: but to expand rules in way that such corners can be added with avoiding possibility of drawing function that is not continuous  (like step function).

Comment: the only rule you need to keep continuity is "don't pick up the pencil". I would say an easy rule to make a corner is, if you're moving up: stop (without picking up the pencil) and start moving down in such a way that makes a sharp point.